# IF. Difference between styles (performance)

Tags: c#

What is the difference between these 2? I am talking about performance and file size.

```
public String Method()
{
    if(condition) return "a"; else return "b";
}
```

and

```
public String Method()
{
    return condition ? "a": "b";
}
```

Which do you prefer and why? Same question for

`(condition == false)` and `(!condition)`

Comment: what about `return condition`?

Comment: I would definetly prefert `return condition`

Comment: One word: readibility.

Comment: Read about premature optimization. You really should not care about "performance and file size" (assembly size?) at this level, unless your proper benchmarks have turned out otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Perform the same function, and are compiled to the IL in the same way . So  the fact is the readability of your code. *If you find the `IF` condition gives your code a better understanding and readability use that and the same goes for Ternary operators*.